# Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors

Tags: c#, struct, stopwatch

I'd like to define a struct that includes StopWatch and then an array of struct.

```
    struct SWExecutionTime
    {
        public Stopwatch swExeTime;
        public int intSWRecCount;
        public double dblSWResult;
    }

    SWExecutionTime[] SWExeTime = new SWExecutionTime[10];
```

It shows run-time error `System.NullReferenceException` when I try to do this:

```
    SWExeTime[0].swExeTime.Start();
```

The initial value of `intSWRecCount` and `dblSWResult` are zero, so I don't need to have a constructor to initialize these variables. The only variable that needs initialization is swExeTime (apparently). C# also shows the error `Structs cannot contain explicit parameterless constructors` when I use constructor without any input parameter.

How can I fix this?

Comment: `new SWExecutionTime()` only instantiates the struct; it does not create a new stopwatch object within the struct.  If you want to do that, write a constructor for the struct, or provide a default instantiation.

Comment: constructor with array? why downgrade?

Comment: I have no idea what that means.  Without some sort of construction, there's no hope of having a stopwatch object in there.  Remember, `int` and `double` are primitive types; the compiler can assume a default value of zero for them.   The same is not true of the StopWatch class.

Comment: Alternatively, use a `class` instead of a `struct`.  Then you can write your parameterless constructor without the compiler complaining.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a class, why are you stuck on structs?

```
class SWExecutionTime
{
    public Stopwatch SWExeTime { get; } = new Stopwatch();
    public int SWRecCount { get; } = 0;
    public double SWResult { get; } = 0;
}
```

Also, follow best practices for naming.